# Wrong dependencies while upgrading to debian 12

Tags: debian, apt, parted

I'm upgrading my debian 11 to 12 version and I'm blocked with apt. Error:

parted: depends libparted2 (=3.4-1) but 3.5-3 will be installed (or "is installed" according to commands done)
do apt --fix-broken install without package or give the solution

or similar my computer talks me in polish :)

`apt --fix-broken install` gives

```
dpkg-query: warning: no list of packages for parted - suppose no files installed
dpkg-mainscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/doc/parted contains files not owned by package 'parted:amd64', cannot switch to simlink
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/parted_3.5-3_amd64.deb (unpack)
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can I just remove the parted[].deb archive to unblock this situation? Or have you other solution?

Comment: I gather you can't `apt remove parted`? oh, wait, you're half way through an upgrade? what have you done so far regarding upgrading to 12

Comment: Well, I did all steps described on debian.org (except "backup your system" :>). As reboot sometimes does miracles, I attempt it, so now I'm in recovery mode. ```apt install --reinstall libparted2``` reinstalled the newer version. I wanted to force installing 3.4 version, but I haven't internet connection despite "eth0 [] state up".  I feel like I'm good for a fresh install of bookworm...

Comment: I'd consider uninstalling parted, then if that's the only roadblock, you can install it once you've managed to upgrade to Debian 12

Comment: Is there another way to achieve unistalling anything since `apt` is blocked till I haven't the right version of libparted2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've found the solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
$ sudo dpkg-configure -a
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

here: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/unmet-dependencies-apt-get

It have unblocked aptitude and upgrade continued till the free space gone out again. So if your system partition has about 5 years, do a fresh install immediately - now the system partition needs between 17 and 25 GB!

Comment: Did you check what use so much space on your root partition? You can run `apt clean` to free some space (but don't do it in the middle of an upgrade). And run `ncdu -x /` to see what use the most space. You probably have storage used by some software, that may be deleted safely.

Comment: *So if your system partition has about 5 years, do a fresh install immediately* This is not a good advice. On my Debian 12 (that I upgraded about 4 times), the base filesystem uses less than 10 GB.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. _And run ncdu -x / to see what use the most space. You probably have storage used by some software_ It's a pity that you couldn't give me this advice before, after a week of battle with upgrade incessantly interrupted for lack of space  and dozens of `apt clean` to free up the space that didn't work being blocked by.. lack of space, I did a fresh install and it asked me between 17 and 25 GB for the system partition. I didn't reinstalled yet all my software and /usr, /var and /boot takes about 6,5 GB after `apt clean` etc.